# Very basic derivative question 10

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I struggle to break up things like $\frac {df}{dz}$ into partial derivatives as I'm not sure how it works.

I am reading and I see that if $f$ is a complex function and $z=x+iy$ that

$$
\frac {df}{dz}= \frac {\partial u}{\partial x}+i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$

How does the LHS equal the RHS?

I am aware of the Cauchy Riemann equations if that is relevant.

I know it's an easy concept it's just it's always been brushed over and never properly taught to me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: yes, why does $\frac {df}{dz}= \frac {\delta u}{\delta x}+i \frac{\delta v}{\delta x}$

Comment: use \partial instead of \delta in the future

Comment: noted, thank you

Comment: When the function is derivable then directional derivatives exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $f(z)=f(x+i\, y)=u(x,y)+i\, v(x,y)$.
Now the whole idea behind the complex derivative is that it doesn't matter from which direction at a certain point in the complex plane you take the limit for the derivative.
If it would you would have infinite different derivatives in one point $z_0$ which isn't really useful at all.
So what follows is that $$\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}z}=\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}y}$$
Ultimately we get $$\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}z}=\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\,\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$